# Converting pixel values from a (x, y, colour/ coordinate colour) format to a 32-bit image

Tags: python, pixel

I have a string of 4 values in the (x, y, colour/ coordinate colour) format that I want to convert to a 32-bit image. I realised that you can use a fork of PIL (Pillow) from Python to do this but I've only found info here regarding the opposite process.

How do I go about doing this and are there any alternative methods to doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by a "32-bit" image? What fork are you talking about? Please provide more details

Comment: What is your input? what is your desired output? what have you done so far?

Comment: If you only have 4 values it's going to be a very small image, surely?

Comment: Hi all. To clarify, I've been given these 4 values. (9,15, #5E5547 ), (3,0, #846863 ), (4,8, #554E41 ), (6,8, #66685A )

Comment: I believe that the information that I received is incomplete and limited, limiting my ability to ask a more specific question and leading me to believe that either this is a very small image of simply an incomplete one. My apologies!